# JPA representation of lines and points

Tags: jpa

I'm relatively new to using JPA but I've spent a fair bit of time researching the annotations and how to use them. I'm developing an app where I have paths, line-segments, and points. Each path has 1 or more line segments. Each line-segment has a sequence number, start point (X/Y), and end point (X/Y). Points can be reused (a requirement). That is, a point can belong to one or more line-segments. The point reuse seems to be the thing that is the pain point here. What I was hoping for was a way to apply the annotations in a way such that once all line-segments that reference a given point have been deleted, that the point is automatically deleted. Below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. If there isn't a way to specify this behavior then I'll have to do something where I issue a custom HQL delete query after each line-segment delete to delete any points that are no longer referenced. Doable but it seems like there should be a better way. If anybody can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "path_tbl")
public class Path
{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "path", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("sequence_number ASC")
    private List<PathSegment> lines = new ArrayList<>();
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "line_tbl")
public class PathSegment {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "path_id")
    private Path path;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="start_point")
    private Waypoint start;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="end_point")
    private Waypoint end;
    @Column(name="sequence_number")
    private int sequenceNumber;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "waypoint_tbl")
public class Waypoint {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private int x;
    private int y;
}
```

Comment: I do not think that this behavior is realizable with just annotations. Especially not, if you have two relations of the same type. _'That is, a point can belong to one or more line-segments.'_ So the correct relation for `start` and `end` should be `@ManyToOne`. Further make these relations bi-directional and you will have references to all `PathSegments` where a `Waypoint` is the starting or ending point. I think that makes deletion of unreferenced points simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I've come to the conclusion that what I thought I can do is not really feasible. What I was working with was implemented differently than the code I posted. I just posted what I thought I wanted it to look like. The code I'm dealing with works but it just seemed more complicated than it should be. Turns out the complexity is necessary. Thanks again!